# how to solve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in Android Studio?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

In order to solve this error in eclipse "Conversion to Dalvik format failed:Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536". I am trying to execute the same Android project in Android Studio, but unfortunately it does not have any error in compile and build to execute. After execution, while starting the activity. It gives java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. Where the error occurs, Please provide the way to find or solve this problem?

Comment: Post your logcat showing the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

You should make your application multi-dex. For more imformation:

1. https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
2. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/multidex/MultiDexApplication.html

Once you've done that, if you still get NoClassDefFound, you should run the dexMainClasses script for classes that must be in the main classes.dex file:

1. http://blog.osom.info/2014/10/multi-dex-to-rescue-from-infamous-65536.html
2. http://blog.osom.info/2014/10/generating-main-dex-list-file.html

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try this and let you know.